# How to solve the given definite integral in terms of Bessel functions?

Tags: definite-integrals, bessel-functions

This is the integral that came after a series of calculations in an online physics lecture. It was told that this can be answered in terms of Bessel functions.

$$I=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x\,\sin(a\sqrt{m^2+x^2})\,e^{ixb}}{i b\sqrt{m^2+x^2}} dx$$

$a,~m~$ and $~b~$ are constants. $i=\sqrt(-1)$

I don't have any idea how to solve it. I need a hint to proceed.

Comment: Is $\iota=i$ ? If it is, may be you could change the notation.

Comment: Yeah, it's iota.

Comment: It could be helpful if you posted that this is the integral that describes the Wightman function in a massive scalar QFT in 2-D instead of just posting the integral without any context. Somebody might be able to fill in with a reference.

Comment: I haven't studied QFT yet so I don't know the function you are talking about. This integral was a part of integral while solving the Klein Gordon equation using Green Functions.